# What does HQ mean in SeleniumHQ?

Tags: selenium

Use Selenium a lot, but wondering the folowing question

Just a little bit curious, I am wondering anyone has the diea wtat is HQ mean in SeleniumHQ?

Comment: What does HP...mean in above answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"HQ" is +1 better than "HP".  Just like "Selenium" is the cure for "Mercury" poisoning.

Comment: I always thought it stood for the obvious Head Quarters!

Comment: @Nashibukasan You're right, that's what it stands for.  It was a silly question and it deserved a silly answer :-)

Comment: But the "Mercury poisoning" thing is true.  Selenium's creator picked the name because Mercury Interactive was the dominant test tool company at the time, before HP bought them.